# How to add admob banner in a fragment view?

Tags: java, android

I am new to android development and I am confused about how to add admob banner to a fragment activity(I think its calling fragment). I am modifying a source code.

I have a layout file called fragment_ftp.xml and its as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/statusText"
        android:layout_above="@+id/startStopButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="99dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/ftpAddressText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/startStopButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/start_ftp"
        android:id="@+id/startStopButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_red"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/warningText"
        android:layout_above="@+id/startStopButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ftp_image"
        android:layout_above="@+id/warningText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I had added the admob banner and in the preview, I can see that. Please check the below screenshot.
[image]

But the issues is that, Where should I write the java code for this admob banner. I don't have a corresponding activity for this fragment_ftp.xml.

Searching for fragment_ftp, I could see only a java file as follows.
FTPServerFragment.java

```
package com.filename.fragments;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;


public class FTPServerFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView statusText,warningText,ftpAddrText;
    Button ftpBtn;
    Futils utils = new Futils();
    private MainActivity mainActivity;
    private View rootView;
    private BroadcastReceiver mWifiReceiver = new  BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
                warningText.setText("");
            }
            else{
                stopServer();
                statusText.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.ftp_status_not_running));
                warningText.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.ftp_no_wifi));
                ftpAddrText.setText("");
                ftpBtn.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.start_ftp));
            }
        }
    };
    private BroadcastReceiver ftpReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(action == FTPService.ACTION_STARTED) {
                statusText.setText(utils.getString(getContext(), R.string.ftp_status_running));
                warningText.setText("");
                ftpAddrText.setText(getFTPAddressString());
                ftpBtn.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.stop_ftp));
            }
            else if(action == FTPService.ACTION_FAILEDTOSTART){
                statusText.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.ftp_status_not_running));
                warningText.setText("Oops! Something went wrong");
                ftpAddrText.setText("");
                ftpBtn.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.start_ftp));
            }
            else if(action == FTPService.ACTION_STOPPED){
                statusText.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.ftp_status_not_running));
                ftpAddrText.setText("");
                ftpBtn.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.start_ftp));
            }
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(false);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ftp,container,false);
//        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
        statusText =(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.statusText);
        warningText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.warningText);
        ftpAddrText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ftpAddressText);
        ftpBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.startStopButton);

        SharedPreferences Sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
        int th = Integer.parseInt(Sp.getString("theme", "0"));
        // checking if theme should be set light/dark or automatic
        int theme1 = th == 2 ? PreferenceUtils.hourOfDay() : th;
        ImageView ftpImage = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ftp_image);

        //light theme
        if(theme1 == 0){
            ftpImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_ftp_light);
        }else{
            //dark
            ftpImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_ftp_dark);
        }
        ftpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!FTPService.isRunning()){
                    if(FTPService.isConnectedToWifi(getContext()))
                        startServer();
                    else
                        warningText.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.ftp_no_wifi));
                }
                else{
                    stopServer();
                }
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        mainActivity=(MainActivity)getActivity();
        mainActivity.setActionBarTitle(utils.getString(getActivity(), R.string.ftp));
        mainActivity.floatingActionButton.hideMenuButton(true);
        mainActivity.buttonBarFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mainActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
    @Override
    public  void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void startServer() {
        getContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(FTPService.ACTION_START_FTPSERVER));
    }

    private void stopServer() {
        getContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(FTPService.ACTION_STOP_FTPSERVER));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        updateStatus();
        IntentFilter wifiFilter = new IntentFilter();
        wifiFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        getContext().registerReceiver(mWifiReceiver,wifiFilter);
        IntentFilter ftpFilter = new IntentFilter();
        ftpFilter.addAction(FTPService.ACTION_STARTED);
        ftpFilter.addAction(FTPService.ACTION_STOPPED);
        ftpFilter.addAction(FTPService.ACTION_FAILEDTOSTART);
        getContext().registerReceiver(ftpReceiver,ftpFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        getContext().unregisterReceiver(mWifiReceiver);
        getContext().unregisterReceiver(ftpReceiver);
    }
    private void updateStatus(){
        if(FTPService.isRunning()){
            statusText.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.ftp_status_running));
            ftpBtn.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.stop_ftp));
            ftpAddrText.setText(getFTPAddressString());
        }
        else{
            statusText.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.ftp_status_not_running));
            ftpBtn.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.start_ftp));
        }
    }
    private String getFTPAddressString(){
        return "ftp://"+FTPService.getLocalInetAddress(getContext()).getHostAddress()+":"+FTPService.getPort();
    }
}
```

I this the java page where I shall write the admob call?

Comment: What do you mean you don't have a corresponding activity? You can either use that layout in an Activity, or you need to load the Fragment into the Activity.

Comment: Hi, I can see the fragment_ftp layout only in the above java file. But I was not able to add the admob code in that Java file.

Comment: I do not see any code related to ads in that file, so you have to be more clear about why you are unable to add it

Comment: Ok while adding its showing errors. Let me add it and show you.. Shall i add the code under  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { }

Comment: Once you include the line `rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView)`, what is the problem?

Comment: `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` is the method of an Activity, not a Fragment. I might suggest you learn about simple Fragments first. All the FTP code is useless to your question

Comment: I had given like this.  mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);   and its shown findViewById cannot resolved. Can you tell me why it happened?

Comment: Because you aren't in an Activity. Again, I suggest you learn about Fragment's and how to find views in them. Look at the other usages of `findViewById` in that same class for examples

Comment: So please show me the final code.

Comment: I don't have the final code. I already told you that `findViewById` cannot be used without using `rootView`. (Look in the `onCreateView` method).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121682/discussion-between-droid-genie-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 1):

try and use this code solve the issue

http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-how-to-integrate-google-admob-in-your-app/

Answer (score 0):

your code java has to be added inside onCreateView function in FTPServerFragement like this :

```
public class FTPServerFragment extends Fragment {

TextView statusText,warningText,ftpAddrText;
Button ftpBtn;
Futils utils = new Futils();
private MainActivity mainActivity;
private View rootView;
private BroadcastReceiver mWifiReceiver = new  BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI){
            warningText.setText("");
        }
        else{
            stopServer();
            statusText.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.ftp_status_not_running));
            warningText.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.ftp_no_wifi));
            ftpAddrText.setText("");
            ftpBtn.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.start_ftp));
        }
    }
};
private BroadcastReceiver ftpReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action == FTPService.ACTION_STARTED) {
            statusText.setText(utils.getString(getContext(), R.string.ftp_status_running));
            warningText.setText("");
            ftpAddrText.setText(getFTPAddressString());
            ftpBtn.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.stop_ftp));
        }
        else if(action == FTPService.ACTION_FAILEDTOSTART){
            statusText.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.ftp_status_not_running));
            warningText.setText("Oops! Something went wrong");
            ftpAddrText.setText("");
            ftpBtn.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.start_ftp));
        }
        else if(action == FTPService.ACTION_STOPPED){
            statusText.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.ftp_status_not_running));
            ftpAddrText.setText("");
            ftpBtn.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.start_ftp));
        }
    }
};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(false);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ftp,container,false);
//        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
    statusText =(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.statusText);
    warningText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.warningText);
    ftpAddrText = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ftpAddressText);
    ftpBtn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.startStopButton);
    //your ads 
    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
        }
    });
    mAdView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);



    SharedPreferences Sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext());
    int th = Integer.parseInt(Sp.getString("theme", "0"));
    // checking if theme should be set light/dark or automatic
    int theme1 = th == 2 ? PreferenceUtils.hourOfDay() : th;
    ImageView ftpImage = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ftp_image);

    //light theme
    if(theme1 == 0){
        ftpImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_ftp_light);
    }else{
        //dark
        ftpImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_ftp_dark);
    }
    ftpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!FTPService.isRunning()){
                if(FTPService.isConnectedToWifi(getContext()))
                    startServer();
                else
                    warningText.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.ftp_no_wifi));
            }
            else{
                stopServer();
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
    mainActivity=(MainActivity)getActivity();
    mainActivity.setActionBarTitle(utils.getString(getActivity(), R.string.ftp));
    mainActivity.floatingActionButton.hideMenuButton(true);
    mainActivity.buttonBarFrame.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mainActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
}
@Override
public  void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void startServer() {
    getContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(FTPService.ACTION_START_FTPSERVER));
}

private void stopServer() {
    getContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(FTPService.ACTION_STOP_FTPSERVER));
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    updateStatus();
    IntentFilter wifiFilter = new IntentFilter();
    wifiFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    getContext().registerReceiver(mWifiReceiver,wifiFilter);
    IntentFilter ftpFilter = new IntentFilter();
    ftpFilter.addAction(FTPService.ACTION_STARTED);
    ftpFilter.addAction(FTPService.ACTION_STOPPED);
    ftpFilter.addAction(FTPService.ACTION_FAILEDTOSTART);
    getContext().registerReceiver(ftpReceiver,ftpFilter);
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    getContext().unregisterReceiver(mWifiReceiver);
    getContext().unregisterReceiver(ftpReceiver);
}
private void updateStatus(){
    if(FTPService.isRunning()){
        statusText.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.ftp_status_running));
        ftpBtn.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.stop_ftp));
        ftpAddrText.setText(getFTPAddressString());
    }
    else{
        statusText.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.ftp_status_not_running));
        ftpBtn.setText(utils.getString(getContext(),R.string.start_ftp));
    }
}
private String getFTPAddressString(){
    return "ftp://"+FTPService.getLocalInetAddress(getContext()).getHostAddress()+":"+FTPService.getPort();
}
}
```